# PHP - Latte template foreach property of non-object

Tags: php, nette, latte

I'm currently using [Latte](https://latte.nette.org/) to do things.
What I can't figure out is how to use a foreach loop on a query with it's template variables. My code below would always return in `Trying to get property of non-object`

```
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM table");
    $array = array();
    while($fetch = $query->fetch_array()){
    $array = $fetch;
}


$Template["qclisting"] = $array;
```

And the template code

```
{foreach $qclisting as $item}
 <a href="" class="list-group-item clearfix">
  <span class="clear">
    <span>{$item->id}</span>
  </span>
</a>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: For now, please, try to dump your variable like this `{dump $qclisting}` - before foreach cycle - and see what your debug tracy console returns

Comment: @pedrouan It returns:
array (1)
0 => array (2)
0 => "1"
id => "1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template, use

```
$item['id']
```

...instead of...

```
$item->id
```

And, remove the [] from line 4 of your code:

```
$array = $fetch;
```

UPDATE:

If you are only seeing the first row of your output, then I was wrong.  Add back the [] in the fourth line of your code:

```
$array[] = $fetch;
```

Comment: Updated my answer.  It would appear based on comments on your question that you also have an extra dimension in your $qclisting array.

Comment: @P.Nick Well I thought you are coding in nette database, so it couldn't be possible to access it like this though. It's simple solution, for sure.

Comment: @pedrouan My bad for not informing you. However, my code only shows the first database row for some reason... help? (op updated)

Comment: Since you've already accepted answer I assume you want to post another question as this is another point. In tour question don't forget to mention database layer you use.

Comment: Apologies.  Your code is not indented in your example and I mis-read it.  Add back the [] in line 4 of your code: 

    $array[] = $fetch;